# Determine the expression that gives the minimum points of $-\sqrt{3}+2\sin(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3})$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

To do this first I solved for the derivative:

$$(-\sqrt{3}+2\sin(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}))' = \\ 2 \cdot (\sin(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}))' = \\ 2 \cdot \cos (\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}) \cdot (\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3})' = \\ 2 \cdot \cos (\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}) \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \\ \cos (\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3})$$

Then I tried to get an expression that would give me the zeros of the derivative:

$$0 = \cos (\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}) \Leftrightarrow \frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3} = \arccos(0) +2\pi k \lor \pi - \arccos(0) +2\pi k \Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{3x-2\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k \lor \frac{3x-2\pi}{6} = \pi - \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k \Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{3x-2\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi + 4\pi k}{2} \Leftrightarrow\\
3x-2\pi =  (\frac{\pi + 4\pi k}{2}) \cdot 6 \Leftrightarrow \\
3x = 3(\pi + 4\pi k) + 2\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
x = (\pi + 4\pi k) + \frac{2\pi}{3} =  \pi(1 + 4k + \frac{2}{3}) = \pi (\frac{5+12k}{3})  $$

However, I don't know how to get only the minimum points from this, as this gives me both the maximum and the minimum points.

How do I solve this?

Also, my book says the solution is:

$$x = \frac{11\pi}{3}+k4\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Why not eliminate the irrelevant $-\sqrt{3}$ at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function achieves a minimum if and only if 
$$\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=-1,$$
or equivalently,
$$\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi, k\in\mathbb Z.$$
Solving this equation yields that 
$$x=\frac{11\pi}{3}+4k\pi, k\in\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: I see. This way it is much simpler. Is there a way to solve this problem using the method I was trying to use?

Comment: @MarkRead Your way is not exactly correct since the first-order condition does not guarantee minima. You should also check the second-order condition to exclude maxima.

Comment: It could be a good idea that you include your last comment in the answer.